# Check for null and assign to a variable at once in C# 8

Tags: c#

Probably a trivial question, but I'm trying to get up to date with modern C# and I am overwhelmed with all the new features like pattern matching etc.

With C# 8, is there a new way to simplify the following common pattern, were I check a property for being non `null` and if so, store it in a `var` for use within the `if` scope? That is:

```
var item = _data.Item;
if (item != null)
{ 
    // use item
}
```

I could think of this:

```
if (_data.Item is var item && item != null)
{ 
    // use item
}
```

And this:

```
if (_data.Item is Item item)
{ 
    // use item
}
```

Between these, I'd still pick the 1st snippet.

Comment: You might want to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Comment: What's wrong with `_data.Item is Item item`? It will return `true` only if non-null, which seems to be exactly what you want. Beyond that, questions like this where there are many acceptable answers, and the choice of which one is subjective, are not suitable for SO, being both too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: How are you going to "use item"?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think it is subjective to define what is opinion based :) E.g., @GuruStron provided an excellent option I wasn't aware of: `if (_data.Item is {} item) { ... }`.

Comment: In this code `if (_data.Item is var item && item != null)` the check for null is not necessary, because it will never be null.

Comment: @LegacyCode, actually the check for `null` is necessary, because `is var` pattern is always `true`, even if `item` is `null`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#var-pattern.

Comment: There is a difference between var and the actual type is this pattern? Thats sick.

Comment: You can negate the result of `is null` expression, like `if (!(_data.Item is null))`. C# 9 will come with [improved pattern matching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#logical-patterns) and it'd be possible to write `if (_data.Item is not null)`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, but I also want to cache `_data.Item` for use within the `if { } scope`. The accepted answer gives me a one-liner for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Also you can use empty [property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/):

```
if (_data.Item is {} item)
{ 
    // use item
}
```

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: IMHO, this is actually very cool. I even can go deeper, liker this: `if (data.Item is { Category: 42 } item) { /* here only if data.Item != null && data.Item.Category == 42 */ }`. I thought this kind of pattern matching only works for `switch`.

Comment: This is the proper approach. It is ugly, but it's the best option.

Comment: @GuruStron, do you know by chance if there is any overhead in the generated IL code for this? Or does it get inlined as a simple `null` check?

Comment: @avo it [seems](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRMAFYxgAupA8rQOYxOAbgDOQ4QF96jEuRSkAsgAoAlLRmNGASwBmpZX22jak0ts4wAtqs1bapO/cYB6F6QCu485atPn5DgAnMoW1qrC/gzSBFoxWnZyGAqKOGoasQF6BnwAhAC8pAB2HgA2pbaZzjSOVQEMbp7eYX519RjBhhFRpPGMMZJAA=) that there is almost no overhead and it is just syntactic sugar for null check and assignment.

Answer (score 5):

Null propagation.

```
var result = _data.Item?.UseItem()
```

or in a method

```
var result = UseItem(_data.Item?.Value ?? "some default value")
```

Comment: not C# 8 feature

Comment: I would think that C# 8 is backwards compatible with C# 6 features... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6

Comment: it is :) still question was mostly about new added features if i undestood it right

Comment: This is a good one and I'm aware of it, but IMHO null propagation is good for a one-liner. If there is a whole scope to work with `item`, I'd rather use `if { }` and skip '.?' within that scope.

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk You are correct! I'll leave it up since OP didn't use it in the post.

Answer (score 4):

This pattern, where `myVariable` may be located outside of the method

```cs
if (myVariable == null)
{
    myVariable = GetSomeFallbackValue();
}
return myVariable;
```

may be shorten as

```cs
return myVariable ?? (myVariable = GetSomeFallbackValue());
```

and the same with C# 8.0 new syntax

```cs
return myVariable ??= GetSomeFallbackValue();
```

The pattern is often used for lazy initialization in Property `getter`, and it's suitable for code written in expression form.

```csharp
private MyClass myBackingField;

public MyClass MyProperty
{
    get => myBackingField ??= new MyClass();
    set => myBackingField = value;
}
```

The value for backing field will be instantiated on first call of the Property `getter`. Thus, the value of the `MyProperty` will never be `null`.

3 operations at once:

- check for `null`
- conditionally assign fall back value
- and return (or use) the result